QNX on RPi4 how do I login the first time
I did all the crazy stuff required to get the QNX RPi4 image. I cooked in the simplest way possible the SD image (cat qnx_sdp8.0_rpi4_quickstart_20241023.img  > /dev/sda) and booted. I press on the icon to open a terminal and I get a text console login prompt. No hint given to what user and or password I should use.
Anyone have a clue ?
Did something else go wrong ? would the imaging tool setup a user for me and give me the password ?

We recommended that you use the username and password qnxuser to start. This will safeguard from changing anything important accidentally. You can use su root or su -c <command> to run commands with more priviledge.
For more information on this (and other things), there is some documentation for the Pi 4 quick start target image in the repo wiki here: https://gitlab.com/qnx/quick-start-images/raspberry-pi-qnx-8.0-quick-start-image/-/wikis/Interacting-with-the-system

Pity that it is hard to find which user one should use in the image.

Hey @louigi600, I'd love to make this better..  Any suggestions? Maybe a pre-login MOTD?

Hi John,
a first login only thing that forces you to change the password for both root and qnxuser.
Else add a note on the default user in the same place where you get told how to download and prepare the imege .

Well it looks like
username: root
password: root

works ... but compared to the single 1.44 Mb floppy QNX 4 demo back in the 1990's this is a very disappointing experience.
Might I add that if the new QNX 8 RPi demo had a full option busybox instead of bash it would have been more useful than it is currently.
